# socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied) (tried adding internet permission)

Tags: java, android

I have tried adding internet permission and almost all solutions that were previously given, but it doesn't work.

```
public class SignupActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private Context context;

    public SignupActivity(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        String fullName = arg0[0];
        String userName = arg0[1];
        String passWord = arg0[2];
        String phoneNumber = arg0[3];
        String emailAddress = arg0[4];

        String link;
        String data;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String result;

        try {
            data = "?fullname=" + URLEncoder.encode(fullName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
            data += "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(passWord, "UTF-8");
            data += "&phonenumber=" + URLEncoder.encode(phoneNumber, "UTF-8");
            data += "&emailaddress=" + URLEncoder.encode(emailAddress, "UTF-8");

            link = "http://192.168.0.4/one/signup.php" + data;
            URL url = new URL(link);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            result = bufferedReader.readLine();
            Log.d("result:",result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception123: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String jsonStr = result;
        Log.d("result:",result);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                Log.d("one","ok");
                String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data inserted successfully. Signup successfull.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (query_result.equals("FAILURE")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Data could not be inserted. Signup failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't connect to remote database.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error parsing JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Couldn't get any JSON data.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

What else could be wrong?
How to resolve it?

Comment: are you running the code on emulator?

Comment: nope in a live device.

Answer (score 0):

Copy Paste these exact lines in your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following: So your Android Device Will Contact with Internet . Add this Code on `AndroidManifest.xml` File

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```